# Getting dynamically generated HTML controls when using UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html

I'm generating HTML elements on the fly using javascript. These controls are located within an update panel on the browser.

For some reason, I'm unable to access those elements in the Page.Form[] array.

Is there a reason for this?

My current solution creates an array of strings, turns that into a JSON string, stores that in a hidden variable which gets posted back to the server as the hidden field was defined before in server side code.

Markup

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">

    <ContentTemplate>
     <div id="dynamicInputsGoHere" class="hiddenContent" runat="server"></div>
    </ContentTemplate>
```

Javascript to create inputs

```
for (i = currentSize; i < numberInputsToCreate; i++) {
                html += "<input type='text' id='inputNum" + i.toString() + "' />";
            }
$('#dynamicInputsGoHere').append(html);
```

I'm trying to access the dynamic inputs that were generated by javascript when the update panel posts back.

Comment: are u saying that the hidden field where you store data is dynamically created from the client itself...?

Comment: There very probably is a reason for this, yes. We're unlikely to work it out without any code to look at, though. Is the panel inside the form tag? How are you generating the form elements (and setting the names, can be problematic in IE), etc...

Comment: You're making things much harder on yourself. The purpose of the UpdatePanel control in the first place is to be able to use server-side code to power an "Ajax-based" UI. Really you can either use the UpdatePanel, or roll the Ajax yourself. It isn't meant/designed to be used both ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give your input elements a [`name` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#control-name) in order for them to get submitted with the form (and available in `Request.Form`):

```
for (var i = currentSize; i < numberInputsToCreate; i++) {
    var name = "inputNum" + i;
    html += '<input type="text" id="' + name + '" name="' + name + '" />';
}

$('#dynamicInputsGoHere').append(html);
```

Then on the server, access them as:

```
string value0 = Request.Form["inputNum0"];
string value1 = Request.Form["inputNum1"];
string value2 = Request.Form["inputNum2"];
```

You're probably best to send `numberInputsToCreate` in a hidden field (`type="hidden"`) and use a loop on the server to pluck the values out.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible to access the HTML elements created by javascript in codebehind.

These controls don't have runat="server" property. So it is not possible to get those controls in codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** Does this programming exist inside a MasterPage or UserControl or any other control that implements `INamingContainer`? Check your renedered HTML and make sure that you do in fact have a `<div id="dynamicInputsGoHere">` since you have it set as `runat="server"` you could very well have something like `<div id="ctrl0_dynamicInputsGoHere">` and therefor your jQuery won't execute.

Once you've verified the input's are being found by your script you'll probably want to register script with the scriptmanager (just to be safe since you are using the UpdatePanel.)

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "createinputs", @";for (var i = currentSize; i < numberInputsToCreate; i++) {
    var name = ""inputNum"" + i;
    html += '<input type=""text"" id=""' + name + '"" name=""' + name + '"" />';
}
$('#dynamicInputsGoHere').append(html);", true);
```

**When your looking for values in code behind you'll have to check in `Request.Form["inputNum"+i]`.**