# Cannot get inner html of a div in asp.net on server

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a div named canvas.

When I try to get its `InnerHTML` property on postback it shows it has empty html contents.

Why isn't this property populated?

### aspx code

```
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="canvas" clientidmode="Static" runat="server" class="ui-droppable" 
             style="width: 1363px; height: 766px;">
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

### C#

```
string finalHTML = canvas.InnerHTML;
```

[image]

Comment: it is empty so what you expect from it?

Comment: I am dynamically adding its content

Comment: yes and last I want to get its all element

Comment: does that help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570540/getting-dynamically-generated-html-controls-when-using-updatepanel

Comment: So, was any of the answers helpfull? Did you manage to solve this issue? Please update this SO item; maybe you can check 1 of the answers as 'correct'...

Answer (score 0):

to modify style of you div, you can use style attribute:

```
canvas.Attributes["style"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only access the data submitted through proper form fields like `<input>`, `<select>` or `<textarea>`. These fields either have a `runat="server"` attribute so you can access them directly in your code behind, or you can give the fields a `name` attribute so you can fetch them through the Request.Form object...

Maybe you can change the field into a `<textarea>`, or migrate to using AJAX to post HTML data to your application.

Answer (score 0):

The value won't be accessible unless the event triggering the postback is defined in the panel triggers - http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers

When using update panels, only "parts" of the page are posted back to the server, decreasing HTTP traffic and providing AJAX functionality.  If you don't specify a trigger for this UpdatePanel, the contents within the UpdatePanel are never sent back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

try to use asp.net Hidden Field to get innerHTML of canvas.
Use jquery to get HTML of div and initialize it into hidden field.

```
$("#hiddenfieldID").val = $("#canvas").innerHTML;
```